# Solve a system of differential equations of the wireless power transmission system

Tags: differential-equations

I'm going to understand power transmission system (by using LRC circuit), at least I need to solve differential equations by using MMA (analytically if it exist), and plot it.

According this [paper](https://qubeshub.org/community/groups/simiode/publications?id=3139&tab_active=about&v=1) the wireless power transmission system can be modelled by following system of differential equations:

[image]

[image]
where V1 is AC voltage (Sinusoidal form), V1=V0 k*Cos[t];

```
R1 = 2; c1 = 1/5; L1 = 1; V0 = 220; \[Omega] = 60;
R2 = 2; c2 = 1; L2 = 1;
M = 1;
ic = {i1[0] == 0, i1'[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0, i2'[0] == 0};
sys = {L1*i1''[t] + M i2''[t] + R1 * i1[t] + 1/c1 i1[t] == V0 * \[Omega]*Cos[\[Omega] t],
       L2*i2''[t] + M i1 ''[t] + R2 * i2[t] + 1/c2 i2[t] == 0}
```

I tried to use DSolve and NDSolve but there is no answer

```
{I1, I2} = NDSolveValue[{sys, ic}, {i1, i2}, {t, 1, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: It works with  M=.99 (M=1 is a very special case)

Comment: Would the terms in R be i1'[t] rather than i1[t]?
sys = {L1*i1''[t] + M i2''[t] + R1 * i1'[t] + 1/c1 i1[t] == V0 * \[Omega]*Cos[\[Omega] t],
       L2*i2''[t] + M i1 ''[t] + R2 * i2'[t] + 1/c2 i2[t] == 0}

Comment: @EricBrown You are correct, op translated the paper equation wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Your system is not setup correctly as it leads to `0===1`

Proof

```
R1 = 2; c1 = 1/5; L1 = 1; V0 = 220; ω = 60;
R2 = 2; c2 = 1; L2 = 1;
M = 1;
ic = {i1[0] == 0, i1'[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0, i2'[0] == 0};
sys = {L1*i1''[t] + M i2''[t] + R1*i1[t] + 1/c1 i1[t] == 
   V0*ω*Cos[ω t], L2*i2''[t] + M i1''[t] + R2*i2[t] + 1/c2 i2[t] == 0}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Look closely at the above, You will see `i1''+i2''` shows in both equations. Solving for `i1''+i2''` from the second gives `i1''+i2''= - 3 i2[t]` Substituting this in the first gives

```
newsys=7 i1[t]-3 i2[t]==13200 Cos[60 t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the system become an algebraic equation. Not differential equations.

The above is what you want to solve now. But it is one equation, two unknowns.

But lets try your initial conditions to see what happens. At `t=0` you say that `i1[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0` hence at `t=0` newsys becomes

```
 0==13200
```

Which can not be correct.

No wonder NDSolve got so confused.  May be some of the parameters are wrong or you translated the equations wrong.

---

**Update**

After seeing the comment above by Eric Brown and looking at the paper, yes, you seem to have made translation error. it should be `R1*i1'[t]` and not `R*i1[t]` in the first ode, also in the second ode it should be `R2*i2[t]'`. Fixing these gives

```
R1 = 2; c1 = 1/5; L1 = 1; V0 = 220; ω = 60;
R2 = 2; c2 = 1; L2 = 1;
M = 1;
ic = {i1[0] == 0, i1'[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0, i2'[0] == 0};
sys = {L1*i1''[t] + M i2''[t] + R1*i1'[t] + 1/c1 i1[t] == 
   V0*ω*Cos[ω t], L2*i2''[t] + M i1''[t] + R2*i2'[t] + 1/c2 i2[t] == 0}

{I1, I2} = NDSolveValue[{sys, ic}, {i1, i2}, {t, 1, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{I1[t], I2[t]}, {t, 1, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]